# Add a column name in incremental manner using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where columns are week,year,value,created date othercolumn have numbers as column name .
[image]

look at the image attached .Except the `category`,`week`,`created_date` and `year` column, I need all columns to have a random column name in this manner: `col1`,`col2`,`col3` using pandas

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this example:

```
  22 57 64 category week created_date year  X
0  x  x  x        x    x            x    x  x
```

You can use a custom function to [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) your columns, with help of [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import count

keep = {'category', 'week', 'created_date', 'year'}

c = count(1)

out = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x if x in keep else f'col{next(c)}')
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 category week created_date year col4
0    x    x    x        x    x            x    x    x
```

Alternatively, if you want to rename the integers only:

```
from itertools import count

c = count(1)

out = df.rename(columns=lambda x: f'col{next(c)}' if isinstance(x, int) else x)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 category week created_date year X
0    x    x    x        x    x            x    x x
```

##### random names

You can also use UUIDs (here short uuids for clarity):

```
# pip install shortuuid
import shortuuid

df.rename(columns=lambda x: shortuuid.uuid() if isinstance(x, int) else x))
```

Example output:

```
  QCU9M2rxT4L2U8DGUAixkW fsxdN3aLaVDVjq3HAGCyYW HoGLKTRctpubfwqUp6rmEF   
0                      x                      x                      x  \

  category week created_date year  X  
0        x    x            x    x  x
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution :

```
to_exclude = ["category", "week", "created_date", "year"]
to_rename = df.columns.difference(to_exclude) #[22, 57, 64]

df.rename(columns={c:f"col{n}" for (c,n) in zip(to_rename, range(1, to_rename.size+1))})
```

Output (*columns*) :

```
#['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'category', 'week', 'created_date', 'year']
```